# How to save/load cookies to/from SharedPreferences with net.java.CookieManager?

Tags: android, android-cookiemanager

In order to manage session through cookies in my `HttpURLconnection` I use

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Now when I exit my app the cookies are deleted. How can I save them to `SharedPreferences` and reload them to the `CookieManager`?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Can i know how implemented this functionality